# Network Analyst Add City Boundary as Polygon Restriction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, polygon-creation

I have a network I am trying to create but am finding the service area polygon I create are "leaking" outside of the city boundary.

I was curious if there was a way to add the polygon as a restriction so that these polygon are "snapped" to the city polygon?

I have tried to add it as a restriction polygon but I come up with errors for the multiple locations I am attempting to create a service area for. I also converted my polygon to a line and utilized the snap feature in Layer Properties, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Adding the city boundary as a restriction or *barrier*? You'd want the latter. You could also just trim your service polygons using the boundary after analysis. What errors? Note if you have a city limit *polygon* as a restriction or barrier to all of the network inside of it, you're going to get errors or a failure since the entire network is covered by the barrier/restriction. You probably want the boundary as a *line* barrier. Screenshots might be helpful here.